# Is there a way to use ignore case only for autocompletion in insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, letter-case

I know I can `:set ignorecase smartcase` to get autompletion to be case-insensitive **but** this has the side-effect of making *all* searches case-insensitive unless they contain an uppercase character.

I have tried the following to attempt a per-command setting of `ignorecase`, but had no luck:

```
inoremap <C-N> <C-\><C-O>:let b:last_ic = &ignorecase \| set ignorecase<CR><C-N><C-\><C-O>:let &ignorecase=b:last_ic \| unlet b:last_ic<CR>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not straight-forward, but it's possible to do this with `:h map-<expr>` and some script:

```
augroup toggle_compl_ignorecase
  autocmd!
  autocmd CompleteDone,InsertLeave *
        \ if exists('s:ignorecase') |
        \   let &ignorecase = s:ignorecase |
        \   unlet! s:ignorecase |
        \ endif
augroup END

function! s:before_complete(key) abort
  if !exists('s:ignorecase')
    let s:ignorecase = &ignorecase
    set ignorecase
  endif
  return a:key
endfunction

for s:key in ["\<c-n>", "\<c-p>", "\<c-x>"]
  execute 'inoremap <expr> '.s:key.' <sid>before_complete("'.s:key.'")'
endfor
```

**Note:** The double quotes and slashes are significant.

The keys `<c-n>`, `<c-p>`, and `<c-x>` are mapped to an expression that returns the final keys to be interpreted by Vim.  In this case all you're doing is using `s:before_complete()` as a passthrough to set `ignorecase`.

To restore `ignorecase`, the autocmd `CompleteDone` is used.  If a menu isn't displayed when pressing any of those keys, `CompleteDone` should still be triggered.  `InsertLeave` is included since it's the ultimate indication that you're not doing anything with completions.  Sanity is always a good thing :>

Comment: Thank you. [I modified it a little](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9981/8520), but wouldn't have gotten the result without your help.

Comment: Also, I added `&l:buftype == '' && ` to both `if`s as this prevents errors in *command* and other special windows.

Answer (score 0):

What I actually used:

```
" case insensitive auto-complete
function! BeforeComplete(key) abort
    if !exists('g:last_ic')
        let g:last_ic = &ignorecase
        set ignorecase
    endif
    return a:key
endfunction
for s:key in ['<c-n>', '<c-p>', '<c-x>']
    execute 'inoremap <expr> '.s:key.' BeforeComplete('''.s:key.''')'
endfor
autocmd CompleteDone,InsertLeave * if exists('g:last_ic') | let &ignorecase=g:last_ic | unlet g:last_ic | endif
```

(Because I got a couple of errors and wanted the variable to use the same scope as the option's.)

Comment: What were the errors?  The scope should be just fine in the original script.

Comment: @TommyA Something like `<SNR>_8s:before_complete function not found`, then another error about an invalid expression that was likely caused by the first. It may have been my mistake from a stray keystroke.

Comment: If it wasn't copied verbatim, you might've typed it out as `<sid>s:before_complete(...)`. In any case, doesn't matter if you got it working. I just prefer to keep utility non-user functions out of the global scope.

Comment: Couldn't tell you, that's reconstructed from vague memory. I did go over it, typing some, mostly because I wanted to understand it and tinker, not just copy & paste.